# Inconsistent displaying of labels on Google Maps (Satellite mode)

Tags: google-maps

I'm logged into my Google account and has Saved a few locations (indicated by the yellow stars below) and have added labels for each of them.
[image]
As you can see, only 2 of the 5 labels show up. Please note that these 2 labels correspond to existing landmarks (they are bus stops) and the 3 non-showing labels correspond to residential houses (that are currently on the market). **How do I get these 3 stars to display the labels I have given them please?** (If I left-click on each, the label is displayed but I would like to show all labels simultaneously.)